# Brieskorn spheres that are S^3

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given pairwise coprime integers $(p,q,r)$, we define a Brieskorn homology 3-spheres by 
$\Sigma(p,q,r)=\{(z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{C}^3 | z_1^p+z_2^q+z_3^r=0, |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+|z_3|^2=1\}$.

Can someone help me show that if say $p=1$, then $\Sigma(1,q,r)$ is homeomorphic with $S^{3}$?

Even $\Sigma(1,2,3)$ would be great.

Thanks

Comment: anyone has some idea?